# How can I copy paste files from a local repo to somewhere untracked by git? Basically as a backup in case I screw up using git

Tags: git

Eventually, I want to push the changes to the remote repo. However, I created a mess in the first place that I need to resolve by deleting branches and overwriting them. Before I do that I would really just like to have all these files somewhere where I cannot delete them accidentally with git. When I simply copy-paste the files without the hidden git folder, the files still seem to be connected to git somehow.
How does that exactly work and how do I create a proper backup?

Comment: "When I simply copy-paste the files without the hidden git folder, the files still seem to be connected to git somehow" - 1) what exactly do you mean by that? 2) nope, that shouldn't happen. Must be you _are_ copying the `.git` folder.

Comment: mmh thanks for answering. I just copy-pasted everything except the hidden git folder. Yet when I changed something using git in the first folder it also affected the newly created folder. Are you saying that should not happen? So I might have made a mistake?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm saying. Maybe windows (or whatever you are using) is copying/doing more than you think. Try copying via command line in a terminal window.

Comment: thank you, I will try!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use GitHub desktop. Every time copy paste your files from your working folder to GitHub folder (documents/github/repoName on my windows).

Using git or VCS is not beginner friendly so by this way you can have a backup somewhere on the web.

I was unable to completely get you so I just suggested something that I understood.